# Why is RestClient Timing out in production and not local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I use a RestClient Post Request for update purposes from one production environment to another which worked without problems until a few days ago. At the moment i always get Timeouts from the second production environment, but when I make the same request locally there is no problem. So there should be a problem with the Environment, which is making the post request.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you give some more information which type of request you are using. My first idea is that the data set on the production environment is much larger than the local data set. If a method loops through the data it can take longer which can cause the timeouts

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the error. it seems like port 80 was blocked by the administrator. He is checking that at the moment.

Comment: Did changing the port solve your problem? I am having the same issue on Heroku